# C# app's installer is installed but doesn't run

Tags: c#, installshield-2015

I created my application's installer with latest InstallShield (Limited Edition for Visual Studio 2015). In fact, these are two independent but talking applications. Smaller one is just responsible for generating data and sending it over COM port and larger one listens for and processes that data.

Now when i created InstallShield installer for smaller one (which is using a Class Library from larger app), its installer is created quite ok and it's running smoothly. But when i create installer for the larger app, it is created fine but when I click the installed shortcut, it simply doesn't start/run.

This larger app has 3 projects, two are class libraries and the third one is the application GUI and the startup project of my app. In the created installer, both class libraries' .dll files are present. Still the project runs from VS15 and from corresponding .exe but not from the installed shortcut.

Where could i possibly go wrong?

Comment: Please respond to my problem someone. Is it too complex? Or too naive? I had followed FoxLearn's youtube video as a tutorial to create installers using installshield. One is working fine, the other created using same procedure is not running. I have now created it several times exploring various options of InstallSheild, but the end result is the same... final exe doesn't run...

Comment: I have just figured out that the installer is not copying the file "Microsoft.VisualBasic.PowerPacks.Vs.dll" to the installation folder and hence, to "Program Files (x86)". Although I never used Visual Basic, and this project is purely in C#, but may be it contains some crucial info. Anyway, when I added it manually, the setup was running fine. So what i did was...

I modified my Setup project and where we Add Primary Output, on the same screen i added above mentioned file and rebuilt the setup. Voila!

Shared for the sake of other newbies...